# Google Sheets: How to highlight the minimum value in a discontinuous range?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is a sample of my spreadsheet:

[image]

I'd like to highlight with bold the earliest date in the yellow / red / blue ranges, without taking into account cells of the other two colours.

Answer (score 0):

This one custom formatting rule, applied to the range D2:P, should work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND(D2<>"",MOD(COLUMN(D2),3)=1,D2=MIN(IF($C$2:$O<>C2,"",$D$2:$P))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well for the yellow and blue categories, but it doesn't highlight anything in the red. It only highlights a date in that category if the cell value is set to 2020-01-18 or earlier.